# How to keep track of classes being instantiated in a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace

Let's say I have a certain file named `main.py`. I want to run this file from another file named `tester.py`. I would be using the command

```
subprocess.checkoutput('python3 main.py', shell=True)
```

I want to get a list of all the classes instantiated and the functions called in `main.py`. Is there any way I could do this?

Edit - I cannot edit the `main.py` file anymore. Hopefully there would be a way without editing the `main.py` file.

Comment: you can try using `dir()` inside main file it returns sth as well as variables imported and functions and classes I think it does at least sth similar and you should look this function up

Comment: Thank you for replying @Matiiss I will check that out. But there is the issue that I cannot edit the `main.py` anymore. Could there be a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do it with a subprocess without modifying either `main.py` or the Python executable. Otherwise, use [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace)

Comment: @pxeger thanks for replying. I am actually using the subprocess just to run the command. I did try `python3 -m  trace --trace main.py `  a I get a huge trace because the classes being called from `main.py` are classes upon classes and the inheritance structure is kind of big. I was not able to parse through the trace file to extract only the uppermost class call, so I thought there must be an easier way. I will look into sys.settrace.

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest I could get:

```
import main
print(dir(main))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering @Matiiss, my `main.py` contains various class instantiations and a function call passing all those classes as a parameter. Would it still work in that case?

Comment: this will give you all class instantitations I think and functions or it did for me oh and all variables so idk how to distinguish if variable is a class instantitation

Comment: Yes, it does give all the class instantiations sequentially, but importing main also run main.py... any way to prevent that?

Comment: there probably is no way to prevent that. but dont u need it to run? well you can try this: `import os` and then `os.system('taskkill /f yourtask')` for that you can look up information in cmd by typing `taskkill /?` also it will probably kill all .py tasks but check that in cmd and also take a look at your task manager for more info about task names or type `tasklist` in cmd (dunno if that will help)